# Is it safe to present UIAlertController (alert style) on iPad without popover?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uialertcontroller

In my app, I display a `UIAlertController` when the user taps on a button on the screen. I either use a `UIAlertController` or a `UIAlertView`, depending on the API availability (since my app supports both iOS 7 and 8).

I simply want to display an alert view to the user so I'm using the .`Alert` style for my `UIAlertController`.

When the user is on an iPad, is it safe to display the `UIAlertController` (`Alert` style) without configuring a `popover`?

I saw some tutorials online. From my understanding, if using a `UIAlertController` (`Action Sheet` style), I need to configure a popover or else the app will crash. I just want to know if it works the same way with an `Alert` style `UIAlertController`.

I did some test on my iPad and the app did not crash without the popover. But I want to make sure this is safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use a `UIPopoverController` with `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` (no matter its style).

iOS will internally use a popover on an iPad when the `UIAlertController` style is "action sheet" but you don't deal with that yourself.

So you have nothing to worry about. Use `UIPopoverController` as-is using the `presentViewController:animated:completed:` method no matter the device and you are fine.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the clarification. I was confused at first because when I had to present a UIActivityViewController before on an iPad running iOS8+, I had to set the sourceView and sourceRect of its popoverPresentationController property. Otherwise, it would crash on iPads running iOS 8. So I wondered if this was also the same case when using UIAlertControllers.

Comment: That's different. Setting the sourceView and other properties are needed with UIAllertController when used as an action sheet.